Intercepting and Cancelling Export in InDesign
I'm developing a plugin for InDesign that includes a pre-export check. If a certain condition is met, I want to display a dialog box prompting the user to confirm or cancel the export.
The functionality works as expected up to the point of user confirmation. I've been unable to find a way to abort the export if the user chooses "Cancel."
Does anyone have experience with interrupting or cancelling the InDesign export process through plugins? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
